# Is the vector constructed in the shared memory of boost.interprocess crash safe?

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess

I construct a boost::vector in the shared memory created by boost.interprocess, then spawn two processes to acccess it: one to write and one to read. The read and write are protected by a process-shared mutex. If the writer process crashes when updating the vector, does the reader can read the vector correctly?

In the following code, the vector is constructed in the shared memory, and all its elements are allocated in the shared memory.

```cpp
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

//Define an STL compatible allocator of ints that allocates from the managed_shared_memory.
//This allocator will allow placing containers in the segment
typedef allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;

//Alias a vector that uses the previous STL-like allocator so that allocates
//its values from the segment
typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;

//Create a new segment with given name and size
managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

//Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

//Construct a vector named "MyVector" in shared memory with argument alloc_inst
MyVector *myvector = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)  //Insert data in the vector
     myvector->push_back(i);
```

Comment: Highly doubt it. Consider the fact that boost::vector uses the heap to manage it's internal array.  Whatever that points to in the first process will not likely be valid in the second process - especially as it resizes when many new elements are added. You might be able to use boost::small_vector as long as you don't resize. But then you might as well just use flat arrays.

Comment: @selbie When constructing boost::vector in the shared memory, the vector will use the shared memory to manage its internal array. The pointer is not a raw pointer and is valid in all proccesses.

Comment: If the writer process crashes part way through a write operation then the vector will be left in an indeterminate state, right?  That being the case, any further use of the vector is potentially undefined behaviour.

Comment: @selbie Interprocess uses stateful allocators with fancy pointers, so that *can* be ok, OP should probably have shown some code to demonstrate this. I'm with G.M.: it's really no different from interrupting an operation in a multithreaded environment (like hard-freezing  a thread)

Comment: @spockwang -  Can you you show some code? I'm nowhere near convinced that boost::vector is automatically aware of an interprocess environment without something passed to it to behave in that mode.

Comment: @selbie nobody said it was automatic. But it's completely idiomatic. Boost Interprocess is an entire library for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I might be able to learn something if `construct a boost::vector in the shared memory` was backed up by a [mcve]

Comment: @selbie I agree. However, the primary goal is to have good questions with useful answers in the future. As luck would have it, there are already many of those about that topic: [if only just mine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20interprocess%20allocator)